# How to import path of api.php in frontend

Tags: javascript, php, frontend, backend

Here is one sample post request which is in **script.js**.I want to send data from this request and store in beckend.So i have created **api.php** file which has All **routes** associated with **controllers**.

In **api.php** , My reqeust route is..

```
Route::post('/task/create/{task_id}','TasksController@create');
```

Request in **script.js.**.

```
    var request = $http({
        method: "POST",
        url: "/api/task/create/1", //// Changes will made here
        data: {id: index, title: $scope.title},
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
    }).catch(function(data){
        alert("error");
    });
```

I am running this files on local server.

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/task/create/1
```

I guess I am inserting the wrong url and i dont how to import that api.php file here and call after making request.So please suggest me to do that.

Answer (score 0):

To call php script you should use

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/api.php?taskid=1
```

inside PHP script you should use

```
$taskid = $_GET['taskid'];
```

As far as I get you try use Express based syntax inside php. If you are using php script to generate JS then you can do that only for front-end

Comment: Thanks for answer,but my question is how to import api.php and what is url in that request??